# Music remixing with a Mac?

Tags: macos, software-rec, music, dj

I have few songs which I want to create mixes from, maybe adding some additional beats, etc.

Does anyone know how I can do this with a Mac (OSX)? Surely this sort of arts-related activity is well suited and would have plenty of existing options.

Comment: I think this should be community wiki since there is no single best answer for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GarageBand](http://www.apple.com/support/garageband/) is for me, the best you can find!!!

You can also try this Remix pack: http://store.apple.com/us/product/MA371Z/A

Answer (score 0):

the good thing about garageband is that it is free.  however, it is pretty basic, and more focused on helping people record live music or use their(apple's) pre-recorded loops than remixing music.
another free option is audacity - http://audacity.sourceforge.net/ , which is also pretty basic but gives you more control (i think) over editing the music.
an option you have to pay for is ableton, which is somewhat expensive but very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

While not exactly the same, this question has some useful answers as well:

https://superuser.com/questions/47102/can-anyone-recommend-dj-software-to-create-music-from-scratch

Answer (score 0):

The most professional software you can find on Mac OS X for offline audio production and remixing is Logic Pro, part of the Logic Studio suite: http://www.apple.com/logicstudio/. This suite also has Mainstage, which is similar to Logic Pro but focused to liver performances.

GarageBand is similar to Logic Studio, but way simpler and less powerful. It's like iMovie to Final Cut Pro. And it's only free if you buy a Mac: it's part of the iLife suite, which indeed is included for free in all the recent Macs. If you already own a Mac, you have to buy it separately.

On the other hand, if you just want to mix two tracks together in a live session (changing each track BPM and the such), like DJs do, give Traktor a try: http://www.native-instruments.com/#/en/products/dj/traktor-pro/.